How to access files on a shared storage in the same network using File System Access API?
I have a requirement to develop a browser based web application. The goal of the application is to manage files on a shared file system, from the browser, as if it was my local file system. If possible with File System Access API or browser extensions. For example, people working for the same company can open the application in the browser, see the hierarchy of the shared file system in the browser, and upload files from their local file system into the shared one, all that from the browser.
Edit: I must not use a cloud solution.
I'm struggling to find an answer if this is possible at all with either File System Access API or browser extensions. If not what are other options?
Again, the goal of the application is to manage files on a shared file system, from the browser, as if it was my local file system.

Yes it's possible

you described more or less any cloud filesystem with a web based interface. there are plenty you can pick from. And by saying shared it means there's a central storage where files are actually stored. but as is this cannot be considered a question suitable for SO

File System Access API is an API to get limited access the filesystem on the client (browser) side, so, not sure that's going to help anyway

@DiegoD Yes, but one of the goals is not to use an external cloud file system. Instead it should be a closed system. A company or perhaps a university. Where else can I ask this kind of a question?

@BorisStanojevic you may better focus your search by looking for a web based filesystem manager running over a file server (this latest part is to address the system hosting the actual files that might not be trivial)

There's about a gazillion ready to go products (Owncloud / Nextcloud, Sharepoint come to mind). I'd look into those before even starting to think about developing something like that myself. Some NAS'es also come with a web-interface; maybe that's an option too?

@Yogi It's for an organization that wants to have this as an internal tool.

Can you guys take a look at this project: https://github.com/mickael-kerjean/filestash
It looks like it accomplishes similar, but not with File System Access API nor extensions.
